# Download multiple files with aria2c in parallel

Tags: bash, shell, aria2

I want to download multiple torrent files in parallel with aria2c with following codes:

```
me@host:~/Downloads$ find . -iregex ".*.torrent"  | while read line; do nohup aria2c "$line" &; done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

To solve the problem with subshells

```
me@host:~/Downloads$ find . -iregex ".*.torrent"  | while read line; do (nohup aria2c "$line" &); done
nohup: nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

But all the processes are in the stop process

```
me@host:~/Downloads$ ps -aux | grep 'aria'| sed "s/$USER/me/g"
me    5807  0.1  0.4  86208 18392 pts/0    S    22:58   0:00 aria2c ./ebd9863a73a5ef22344550a650d169a1.torrent
me    5809  0.0  0.4  85804 17884 pts/0    S    22:58   0:00 aria2c ./53ef22110569d46b445a1e908a7ae88f.torrent
me    5811  0.1  0.4  87336 19408 pts/0    S    22:58   0:00 aria2c ./a51accbbf14c8a05cb82caa7d8bec0c6.torrent
me    5813  0.0  0.4  84260 16528 pts/0    S    22:58   0:00 aria2c ./0eae6a261a340b8af159c0155aa8fab6.torrent
me    5815  0.0  0.3  82972 14400 pts/0    S    22:58   0:00 aria2c ./bf93f4618ba007ff95113156c802812b.torrent
me    5817  0.0  0.4  84256 16376 pts/0    S    22:58   0:00 aria2c ./f5938dd24367ffaf766ef99928660786.torrent
me    5819  0.0  0.4  86132 18440 pts/0    S    22:58   0:00 aria2c ./61ee21f83a33b91674926daf70c34947.torrent
me    5821  0.0  0.4  84100 16296 pts/0    S    22:58   0:00 aria2c ./710fc8dc201568d807aa7709b8fa072a.torrent
me    5823  0.0  0.3  82972 14364 pts/0    S    22:58   0:00 aria2c ./2b9cc942c04a8063bd8d4d8fd98814d9.torrent
me    5825  0.0  0.4  85832 18340 pts/0    S    22:58   0:00 aria2c ./8ffc0566591e1258c151d4d28843c55b.torrent
me    5827  0.0  0.3  82972 15208 pts/0    S    22:58   0:00 aria2c ./d9e39bfe0a907ffb580a975d8c8719d2.torrent
me    5829  0.0  0.3  83692 15616 pts/0    S    22:58   0:00 aria2c ./EDBDB765D87586FDA75C4287A1E9EA1E.torrent
me    5933  0.0  0.0  11928   956 pts/0    S+   23:04   0:00 grep --color=auto aria
```

How could git it done?

Comment: Is there really a problem? `S` means »*interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)*«. When I download something with `aria2c` successfully then `ps` always has state `S` (or `S+`) for me. If your files are not downloading, then maybe there are no peers for your torrents – check the log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know `aria2c`, but a simple way to do things in parallel, is often to use **GNU Parallel**

```
find . -iregex ".*.torrent" -print0 | parallel -0 aria2c
```

This will run, in parallel, one `aria2c` for each core your CPU has until all files are downloaded. If, for some reason, you specifically want to run, say 32, at a time, use:

```
find ... | parallel -0 -j32 ...
```

If you want a progress meter, use:

```
find ... | parallel -0 --eta ...
```

More examples and ideas [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to download multiple torrent files with `aria2c` at once or you want to do it specifically with the commands you've posted? If first, then the following simple command does it:

```
aria2c *torrent
```

Takes all the torrent files in the current directory and downloads them in parallel.